# gradle copy multiline file filter

Tags: filter, gradle

I'm copying a file using the gradle copy task and I want to apply a filter that matches multiple lines using a regex. It seems like the filter task only matches line by line. Is there a way to analyze the entire file at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no multi-line filter. You may have to process the files before or after the copy (with Groovy).

Comment: I could process the files after copy, but this is happening in the war task. Is there a hook to modify the files before they are packaged in the war?

Comment: That hook would be `eachFile`. I'd probably process the files beforehand. If the files come from `src/main/resources`, one place to process them would be in `processResources.doLast { ... }`.

Comment: Unfortunately they're not in process resources. I'm replacing some markers in source code. The issue I'm seeing with eachFile is that I don't know where to write the new file out to. Does it get written to an intermediate location before it goes into the war?

Comment: ad 1. Are these sources part of a Gradle source set? In other words, how do they make it into the War? ad 2. You are right, `eachFile` seems to be a dead end.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to do some replacement in the source before the code goes into the war. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: What kind of sources are we talking? JSPs or the like? Where are they located?

Comment: Yep, jsp/html. They are in my src/main/webapp

Comment: You could reconfigure `project.webAppDir` (e.g. to `build/generated-web`), write a task that copies from `src/main/webapp` to `build/generated-web` and processes the files as needed, and make the `War` task depend on that task.