# Gradle: replace multiple lines using regex within build

Tags: regex, gradle

I managed to use Gradle to replace a string in a file using RegEx but it only works if the searched string is in one line. I haven't managed to replace something that goes over several lines. I tried replaceAll with (?sm) etc but failed. I assume that the process in Gradle works line by line because my RegEx is functional within the IntelliJ search.

build.gradle:

```
rootSpec.eachFile {
    if (it.name == 'xxx.xml') {  
        it.replaceAll("(?sm)<bean id="featureX(.*)</bean>$", "")
    }
}
```

the xml file

```
   <bean id="featureX" class="myClass">
        <property name="title" value="Service"/>
    </bean>
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answer. 
As a workaround I use now a filter and ReplaceAll but I do not replace the
 lines but comment out the lines via Gradle like

```
<!-- DoNotRemove Comment Begin -->
<bean ...
...
</bean>
<!-- DoNotRemove Comment End -->
```

to

```
<!-- DoNotRemove Comment Begin 
<bean ...
...
</bean>
     DoNotRemove Comment End -->
```

Not the best solution but it is ok. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

The code example you've posted isn't valid. Firstly, you can't use replaceAll on a File, secondly, you are trying to use quotation marks inside a String enclosed with quotation marks, and lastly, even if it worked, you are not doing anything with the result.

Also, the regex engine is not something provided by Gradle, but rather the plain Java SDK. So you can read all about it in the Java documentation.

If we just look at the regex itself, you are using the correct flags.

`s` enables DOTALL mode where `.` will match any character including line terminators. This is needed for matching multiple lines.

`m` enables multiline mode, where the `^` and `$` expression matches the beginning/end of each line (not only the beginning/end of string). However, the `$` expression in your example is probably unnecessary and perhaps even unwanted depending on how the XML is formatted. If you need the `$` expression, you also need the `m` flag; otherwise just remove them both.

When I tried your expression, it matches multiple lines just fine. But it also matches everything between the first `<bean>` and the very last `</bean>` element, which is probably not what you want. Try changing the greedy `.*` expression to a reluctant `.*?` expression.

You can also remove the grouping `()` if you are not using it for anything.

Here is an example (in Groovy):

```
def matches = """<root>
    <bean id="featureX" class="myClass">
        <property name="title" value="Service"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="featureY" class="myClass">
        <property name="title" value="Service"/>
    </bean>
</root>""" =~ '(?s)<bean id="featureX.*?</bean>'
if (matches.find()) {
    println matches.group()
}
```

Outputs:

```xml
<bean id="featureX" class="myClass">
        <property name="title" value="Service"/>
    </bean>
```

If this still doesn't work in your Gradle script, you are probably not working on the content you think you are. Try printing it out and validate the regex against it using something like https://regex101.com/ or https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/.

Alternatively, you can also use the [Groovy XmlParser](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html) to parse the XML. This is available in Gradle as long as you use the Groovy DSL (and not the Kotlin DSL or pure Java). Example:

```
def xml = """<root>
    <bean id="featureX" class="myClass">
        <property name="titleX" value="ServiceX"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="featureY" class="myClass">
        <property name="titleY" value="ServiceY"/>
    </bean>
</root>"""

def featureX = new XmlParser().parseText(xml).'bean'.find {it.@id == "featureX"}
def name = featureX.property[0].@name
def value = featureX.property[0].@value
println "FeatureX [$name : $value]"
```

Outputs:

```
FeatureX [titleX : ServiceX]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I want to select / remove the whole text from <bean ... to </bean> and yes there is a copy and paste error. In my original code there are single quotes '(?sm) ... ' instead of double quotes. Like I wrote: The replacement is working fine in my RegEx text editor and when I do it Java/Groovy but when I try to replace it with Gradle/Groovy within the build process (I do not want to replace the text directly in the file in the workspace). All is working fine (like I want, I tested it)  this way (with File -> replaceAll) when I try to replace only the text in one line.

Comment: Another information: I do the replacement in the war { ... } section because the changed files should only be in my war file.

Comment: I found a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953712/gradle-copy-multiline-file-filter?rq=1   but I'm not very happy with the answers.

Comment: Ah, so `rootSpec` is of type `CopySpec` and you are calling `.eachFile` that gives you a `FileCopyDetails`? If that is the case, I don't know how you can call `replaceAll` on it as that method doesn't exist. If you are using one of the `filter` methods, you can see from the [JavaDoc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/ContentFilterable.html#filter-org.gradle.api.Transformer-) that `The Closure will be called with each line`. So you will have to use another method. I don't think you can do it in the CopySpec, but you should be able to do it after.